# Simplest 5 Volt power supply circuit design

Tags: power-supply, power

I am doing a project related to power supply. In that i have designed 5Volt supply some what largely(using transformer,diodes, capacitors) therefore it occupies more space. So can you suggest me a very simple form of 5Volt power supply.

**Edit** (based on author comments)

Input voltage: 230V

Output current: <1A

Comment: *What exactly* is wrong with the power supply design tools that semiconductor manufacturers make available on their web sites for free?

Comment: What's the input voltage?  How much output current?

Comment: @NickAlexeev Sir my Input voltage is 230Volt AC , Output Voltage 5Volt DC

Comment: [again]  What's the required output current?

Comment: @NickAlexeev Sir my Output current is not more than 1A

Comment: I honestly wouldn't even start thinking about tinkering with mains voltage before you are more advanced in the topic of electronics. Stick with the linear transformer for now!

Comment: Are you need a power supply to power your project, or you need to **design** a power supply?

Comment: @johnfound Sir i have designed power supply already but that is large and occupies more space in my board, so could you suggest me alternate design which would be very compact.

Comment: @barani - You didn't answered my question, actually. You simply repeated your question, that I already read. And, please, don't sir me.

Comment: @barani If all you require is a usable, small sized 5 Volt DC supply, you could consider using a cellphone USB charger. If you must incorporate the power supply into your own design, see [this answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/53628/14004) to understand how manufacturers have been incorporating tiny transformers into those small matchbox sized 5 Volt power supplies.

Comment: If you value your life either go with the finished SMPS or regular transformer based design. Having an electrical connection to mains in a non-sealed product really isn't safe.

Comment: ummmm how big a psu tends to be determined by voltage and CURRENT....so, how much current?

Comment: The **simplest** power supply I know of, that operates from around 230 V AC, would be one based on this [answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/78126/power-led-bed-lamp-from-mains) - but it isn't very safe!

Answer (score 2):

Just use a power supply that has a USB connector on it - one that you would use for a cell phone.

Comment: Someone downvoted this, but I think thats best way to do it. Phone chargers are very cheap and relatively safe. "Simplest supply" based on capacitor, without any insulation between mains and circuit is very dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

I'm considering the power you are getting is from the mains Supply.

You can design a capacitor Input supply which can obviate the use of bulky transformer from your circuit. Choosing the input capacitor is the critical part you can refer this link.

http://www.electroschematics.com/5678/capacitor-power-supply/

Moreover you can eliminate the regulator part if you want but supply will be more noisy in this case.

But the precautions should be taken as the Mains will now be directly attached to your board and user will be more susceptible to get electrocuted if not handled properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 7805 IC.By far it is the most simplest way to Create a 5V power supply

http://electrosome.com/power-supply-design-5v-7805-voltage-regulator/

Comment: It'd be worth including some more details from that link in your answer. At the moment if the link dies it wouldn't leave much apart from use a 7805 which wouldn't be a very useful / complete answer.

Comment: I agree with PeterJ, in addition the question currently states 230V input.

Answer (score -5):

the simplest way i know is zener shunt diode regulator circuit that will change your 230 AC voltage to a regulated 5 volt DC if that's what you want the circuit 
contains : a) transformer , b) bridge rectifier , c) capacitor d) resistor , f) zener diode , e) load resistor

Comment: sir, thanks for your comment, but now i am using the components which you have told above. Sir could you suggest any other circuit which does not contain Transformer.

Comment: @barani: Transformer-less designs are *not* recommended for novice amateur EEs.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Sir you are correct but my project need that circuit in order to reduce the size.

Comment: A sketchy answer followed by "*any question ask me*" is not how this site works. Contributors are expected to provide a complete answer, suitably definitive and not requiring a further dialog. In this particular answer, adding a schematic and further details would redeem this answer.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh i would add schematic but this is his project , he wouldn't learn anything if i give him everything, he should do his homework on the subject!

Comment: @ray Please spend some time looking around this web site, as well as reading the site help about what is considered a good or acceptable answer here: Clearly, you are new to the site, hence it is excusable that you don't understand how the site works. Vague hand-waving answers add no value to anyone's life, and are natural down-vote magnets. If you don't want to "do someone's homework", then don't post an answer.